# Detecting the Loopback Adapter

Tags: windows, winapi, network-programming

What is the best way for detecting whether a network interface is a loopback adapter?

The windows API's **GetAdaptersInfo** and **GetAdaptersAddresses** state in the documentation that they will return whether an interface is a loopback through the Type (**MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK**) but neither of these do for the Microsoft Loopback Adapter at least, it is reported as a standard ethernet interface.

I could try checking for the **default MAC** of the Loopback adapter but this can be easily spoofed.

I could check for the name "**Microsoft Loopback Adapter**" in the description but this may have translation issues and may lead to other issues.

**IP addresses** can also be changed.

What is the most robust method for doing this?

Comment: AFAIK, the Loopback Adapter is not supposed to report MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK.  The whole purpose of that adapter is for apps to test their socket I/O locally using an IP adapter that looks and acts like any other ethernet adapter.  MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK is likely reported only by the interface(s) that manage actual loopback IPs (127.0.0.1 for IPV4, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 for IPv6).

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Loopback Adapter is for faking a network.  Its lying to you, because that's its purpose.  [MSDN citation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013).

> The Microsoft Loopback adapter is a
>   testing tool for a virtual network
>   environment where network access is
>   not available. Also, you must use the
>   Loopback adapter if there are
>   conflicts with a network adapter or
>   with a network adapter driver. You can
>   bind network clients, protocols, and
>   other network configuration items to
>   the Loopback adapter, and you can
>   install the network adapter driver or
>   network adapter later while retaining
>   the network configuration information.
>   You can also install the Loopback
>   adapter during the unattended
>   installation process.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Kevin. I know what the loopback adapter is for, I just want to be able to detect it. Why did they include the MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK type if it is never returned?

Comment: I suppose you could conceive of a loopback adapter that was not indistinguishable from a "normal" adapter.  There's a fair chance that whoever was responsible for `MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK` was in no-way involved with the Microsoft Loopback adapter anyway.  Might just be an inconvenient naming overlap.

Answer (score 0):

`MIB_IF_TYPE_LOOPBACK` probably refers to the loopback address 127.0.0.1. It should be possible to find out whether an adapter is a Microsoft Loopback Adapter if it's got a static (or configurable) MAC address (Ethernet address). Or maybe it doesn't have one?

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI, see sample at [WMI Code Creator v1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) :

`strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_TCP",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_TCP instance"
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
Next`

Answer (score 0):

I can detect the loopback adapter by simply looking at the `IfType` member of the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` structure. If it is `IF_TYPE_SOFTWARE_LOOPBACK`, then the adapter is the loopback adapter. Works fine here on Windows 7 and 10.

Answer (score -1):

You could use WMI to check the driver of each network interface.